# Write file using go-fuse (hanwen)

Tags: go, fuse

I’ve created a FUSE filesystem using go-fuse (hanwen). Everything works, but I don't understand how to write to a file.

This code creates a file and it works:

```go
func (me *HelloFs) Create(name string, flags uint32, mode uint32, context *fuse.Context) (file nodefs.File, code fuse.Status) {
    // ... creating...
    return nodefs.NewDevNullFile(), fuse.OK
}
```

Also I see that the saving operation calls this creating function when the file exists.

How can I realize the save function?